# In an A-Frame scene, how to make models from Sketchfab appear with correct size and color?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to do something very basic with a-frame & gltf/glb models, basically want to drop a few models into a scene.

I started with A-Frame's ["Hello WebVR"](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/helloworld/) and just tried to add one model from Sketchfab, but every time I manage to make it work...:

1. The model is huge. Like 100x or 1000x of its "correct" size.
2. The model is completely dark.

I think I missing some basic understanding in setting up models in a scene.

**How could I make models appear correctly, meaning correct size and color?**

Here's one of my tries: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spicy-pretty-singer, just walk back (WASD) A LOT.

If unfamiliar with Glitch: you can see the result by clicking on "Show" at the top, and you can click "remix" (fork) to change the code.

[Sample model from Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/branagh-3-seater-chesterfield-sofa-blue-velvet-571657a0aefd4de3bb02586b4f6e127e) (I tried several, same results).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Size**

The "correct" size is quite is quite a subjective term - if you load the model into a modelling software, lets say blender, then You can check out the original (intented if the converted didn't mess up scaling) dimensions:

[image]

It is huge - like 250m x 70m x 90m huge. Keep in mind - in `a-frame` 1 unit equals one meter.

You can either change it in blender (maya), or just scale the entity:

```
<a-entity gltf-model="#model" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"></a-entity>
```

**2) Dimmed textures**

When in doubt always double check the model with [Don McCurdys gltf model viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)!.

The sofa looks surprisingly good, but there is a catch!

If the encodings (model texture encoding, and renderer output encoding) and lights are matched with the scene, the sofa goes dark:

[image]

If I change the output encoding to sRGB:
[image]

It looks already better. The output encoding is set by the renderers [colorManagement](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/renderer.html#colormanagement) ([source code](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.2.0/src/systems/renderer.js#L35-L36))

With `<a-scene renderer="colorManagement: true">` it looks like in the viewer:

[image]

Turning the texture encoding to `linear` also makes it brighter. To change it in the `gltf-model` - as far as i know - will require a bit of javascript:

```
// wait until the model is loaded
entity.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
  // grab the mesh
  const mesh = entity.getObject3D("mesh");
  mesh.traverse(node => {
    // grab the material and change the encoding
    if (!node.material) return;
    node.material.map.encoding = THREE.LinearEncoding
  })
})
```

Here's the scene:
[image]

[glitch here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-68035050?path=index.html%3A6%3A59)